# Calculating memory footprint of your app running on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I've got a application making a lot of calls towards db and taking a lot of time.

My goal is to make one call towards db and keep objects in the memory so that ought to make it faster.

Keeping these objects shouldn't be a problem since I have a pagination implemented in my app.

In any case how would I measure the "weight" of objects I keep in my memory? So I know my application won't crash on heroku

**Edit**

I wasn't able to figure out the results from this link :

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/GC/Profiler.html#method-c-result

Here are my results :

```
GC 339 invokes.
Index    Invoke Time(sec)       Use Size(byte)     Total Size(byte)         Total Object                    GC Time(ms)
    1              17.152              7027800             12285000               614250        51.99999999999900524017
```

If someone could help me interpret them or tell me how they do it. That'd be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this through using [`GC::Profiler`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/GC/Profiler.html). This will allow you to profile the memory usage and garbage collector activity in a section of your code. You simply do:

```
GC::Profiler.enable

# code you want to profile

puts GC::Profiler.result

GC::Profiler.disable
```

See the doc entry for [`GC::Profiler.result`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/GC/Profiler.html#method-c-result) to understand what is printed out.